# Unable to Copy datacolumn from one data table to another

Tags: c#, .net, datatable

How can I copy 1 data column from 1 data table to a new datatable. When  I try to do it, I get the error Column 'XXX' already belongs to another DataTable.?

```
dataColumn = datatable1.Columns[1];
datatable2 = new DataTable();
datatable2.Columns.Add(dataColumn);
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: If you post code or XML, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code" button (101 010) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can we copy the data of the datacolumn of the datatable to another datatable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2583898/how-can-we-copy-the-data-of-the-datacolumn-of-the-datatable-to-another-datatable)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You cannot copy DataColumns.  What you'll need to do is create a new DataColumn in the new datatable with the same data type as in the old datatable's column, and then you need to run a FOR loop to bring in all the data from the old datatable to the new datatable.

See the following code.  This assumes that the datatables have exactly the same number of rows.

```
DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();

dt2.Columns.Add("ColumnA", dt1.Columns["ColumnA"].DataType);

for (int i = 0; i < dt1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    dt2.Rows[i]["ColumnA"] = dt1.Rows[i]["ColumnA"];
}
```

Also, If the data you are copying are reference types and not value types you might want to see if a .Clone() method is available for the type, or make one yourself.  Just doing 'this = that' in the FOR loop will not work on reference types.

Comment: @Lane Thanks..But I think this approach will be highly expensive as I may have to copy more than 1 column and rows may exceed 1 Million..

Comment: You can copy data in multiple columns in the same loop.  This is the only way to do it.

Comment: Agreed.  This is the only way to do this, if you are copying a column from one datatable to another datatable.  It might not be as expensive as you think.  Try it out and see.

Comment: @SLaks and @Lane - you lie! ;-) You can do it with a DataRelation and a calculated DataColumn as well.

Comment: @Xcaliburp: Not if you subsequently want to change the values in one of the tables.  Also, that requires a common key.

Comment: @SLaks - The common key thing is true, but I'm trying to think of an example where I have wanted to copy a column of data from one DataTable to another and not been doing some kind of joining (like joining a StatusID to the StatusTable to get the StatusName). I can't think of one. So though your point stands, I think it might be a bit of a straw man.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot copy a DataColumn.  (DataColumns are very tightly coupled with their tables)

Instead, you can add a new column with the same name and datatype.

You might be looking for `DataTable.Clone()`, which will create a structual copy of an entire table.  (With the same schema, but no data)

Answer (score 1):

Just a thought, are your DataTables both in the same DataSet?

If so, you can create a named [DataRelation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ay82azad%28VS.71%29.aspx) between the columns of two tables (think foreign key).

Then you can add a Calculated DataColumn to your table that has its [Expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression%28v=VS.71%29.aspx) property set to "Child(RelationName).ColumnName" or "Parent(RelationName).ColumnName" depending on the direction of the relationship.

This will give you the same effect as copying the column, but I believe it only evaluates it lazily. So maybe it will give you what you need.

There is an example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163495.aspx) of how this works. The example uses the *Sum* aggregate function, but you just need to reference the column name and it will duplicate it in your DataTable

```
myDataSet.Relations.Add(
    "Orders2OrderLines", 
    myDataSet.Tables["Orders"].Columns["OrderID"], 
    myDataSet.Tables["OrderLines"].Columns["OrderID"]);

ordersTable.Columns.Add("OrderTotal", typeof(decimal), "Sum(Child(Orders2OrderLines).ExtendedPrice)");
```

HTH

Comment: I'm pretty sure it won't evaluate lazily.  Also, the values in the columns will be permanently linked, which may or may not be what he wants.

Comment: @SLaks - You're right about the linking - it can be good or bad depending on your needs. The reason I think it is lazy is because of the linking. I imagine that internally it's just a delegate that binds to the data in the original table - so not copy actually takes place. I'd love to know if I was wrong as I've never tested this...

Comment: Thanks ..But my DataTables both in the same DataSet.

Comment: @Ananth - Was that a typo? Or did you say your tables ARE both in the same DataSet. If they are, then this will work. If they aren't then this isn't a solution to you. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by the c# can not reuse the object instance created and uses it on multiples DataTables. For this it is necessary to create a new object DataCollumn for each loop iteration.

```
foreach (DataTable table in DATASET.Tables)
{
    DataColumn yourDataCollumn = new DataColumn("Name of DataCollumn", typeof(Your data type));
    // your logic here
}
```

Hope it's help...

Answer (score 0):

I used the below to merge two tables using mostly LINQ and only looping through the rows at the end.  I wouldn't call it pretty but it does work.  Using the join to prevent some of the assumptions listed above.

```
DataTable tableOne = getTableOne();
DataTable tableTwo = getTableTwo();

var oneColumns = tableOne.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
                                 .Select(p => new Column(p.ColumnName, DataType))
                                 .ToArray();

var twoColumns = tableTwo.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
                                 .Select(p => new DataColumn(p.ColumnName, p.DataType))
                                 .ToArray();


var matches = (from a in tableOne.AsEnumerable()
               join b in tableTwo.AsEnumerable() on a["column_name"] equals b["column_name"]
               select a.ItemArray.Concat(b.ItemArray)).ToArray();


DataTable merged = new DataTable();
merged.Columns.AddRange(oneColumns);
merged.Columns.AddRange(twoColumns);

foreach (var m in matches) { merged.Rows.Add(m.ToArray()); }
```

Comment: I don't think they want to merge one table with another, sounds like they just want to seed a table with just one column from the first.

Answer (score -2):

No looping required , Refer this , Hope this should solve your problem...

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable(); 
//fill the dt here 
DataTable dt2 = new DataTable(); 
string[] strCols = {"Column Name to copy"}; 
dt2 = dt.DefaultView.ToTable("newTableName", false, strCols);
```

Comment: Creating a new DataTable is not what was asked in this question. (Also, the second constructor call is superfluous.)