# Adding a column from one Datatable to another datatable of a dataset

Tags: c#, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I am trying to merge two tables in a `DataSet`. The `DataSet` has 2 tables and I want to add a column `TypeofDay` from `Tables[1]` to `Tables[0]` like this. But I get an error here

> *"Cannot set Expression property due to circular reference in the expression."*

How can I fix this? Thank you in advance! This is using c# in VS 2005.

```
DataSet ds = new BusinessLogic.BizLogic().getMonthlyStandings(RepID);

DataColumn newColumn1;
newColumn1 = new DataColumn("TypeofDay");
newColumn1.Expression = ds.Tables[1].Columns["TypeofDay"].ToString();
ds.Tables[0].Columns.Add(newColumn1);

DataView myDataView = new DataView();
myDataView = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
grdMonthlyStandings.DataSource = myDataView;
grdMonthlyStandings.DataBind();
```

Comment: What line to you get the error on?  What is the value of newColumn1.Expression?

Comment: I get the error on the newColumn1.Expression line. what should be on the right hand side of the Expression line to merge the column?!

Comment: Sorry! I actually want to merge the values too. How do i do that?!

Comment: possible [Duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4184698/799558)

Comment: I am not sure about expression , but i will prefer to do something i do at SQL level update column of table 2 from data of table 1