# how to copy datatable column and value to another datatable

Tags: c#, datatable

I have a datatable dt1 with 4 column(Name,Address,Contact,Marks) which has 0 Rows, and I have another datatable dt2 with 2 column(StdName, StdAddress) with few Rows.

when I am doing something like dt1 = dt2.copy(); then my dt1 is getting change. which I don't want.

I want to copy dt2 column and value to dt1. so in my dt1's column(Name and Address) will fill with stdName and StdAddress Value.

Please someone help me how to do that.

Comment: Have you tried anything else other than `Copy()`?

Comment: No, Please tell me some other way to try?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I tried with this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2583898/how-can-we-copy-the-data-of-the-datacolumn-of-the-datatable-to-another-datatable)

```
private void CopyColumns(DataTable source, DataTable dest, params string[] columns)
{
 foreach (DataRow sourcerow in source.Rows)
 {
   DataRow destRow = dest.NewRow();
    foreach(string colname in columns)
    {
      destRow[colname] = sourcerow[colname];
    }
   dest.Rows.Add(destRow);
  }
}

CopyColumns(source, destiny, "Column1", "column2");
```

It help me to solve my problem.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
  for (int i = 0; i < dt2.Rows.Count; i++)
  {
    dt1.Rows.Add(dt2.Rows[i][0], dt2.Rows[i][1]);
  }
```

Comment: I want you to know, that years later, and this is what helped me solve my issue. +1

Answer (score 1):

```
  for (int k = 0; k < dt2.Rows.Count; k++)
  {
    dt1.Rows[k]["Name"] = dt2.Rows[k]["StdName"];
    dt1.Rows[k]["Address"] = dt2.Rows[k]["StdAddress"];
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
 DataTable dtEmp = new DataTable("EMP");
        dtEmp.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(String));
        dtEmp.Columns.Add("Address", typeof(String));
        dtEmp.Columns.Add("Contact", typeof(String));
        dtEmp.Columns.Add("Marks", typeof(String));


        DataTable dtStd = new DataTable("STD");
        dtStd.Columns.Add("StdName", typeof(String));
        dtStd.Columns.Add("StdAddress", typeof(String));

        foreach (DataColumn dc in dtStd.Columns)
        {
            dtEmp.Columns.Add(dc.ColumnName, dc.DataType);
        }
        // Import rows from dtStd Table.
```

Answer (score 0):

try it....

```
    DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
    dt1.Columns.Add("col1", typeof(String));
    dt1.Columns.Add("col2", typeof(String));
    dt1.Columns.Add("col3", typeof(String));
    dt1.Columns.Add("col4", typeof(String));

    DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
    dt2.Columns.Add("col5", typeof(String));
    dt2.Columns.Add("col6", typeof(String));

    dt1.Merge(dt2);
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is older, but where is the data coming from?

If you are querying a sql database, you can just change:

```
    SELECT <column1>, <column2> FROM...

    SELECT <column2>, <column1> FROM...
```

Query and return a datatable with the columns like you want them.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but you can try this....

```
Datatable1.Merge(Datable2)
```

It will give you output like this

Answer (score 0):

```
  for (int k = 0; k < dt2.Rows.Count; k++) {
    dt1.Rows[k]["Name"] = dt2.Rows[k]["StdName"];
    dt1.Rows[k]["Address"] = dt2.Rows[k]["StdAddress"];
  }
```

This worked excellent for me. I just had to rewrite it in VB like this:

```
  For r = 0 To t2.Rows.Count - 1
        t1.Rows(r)("Stat") = t2.Rows(r)("Stat")
        t1.Rows(r)("Dest") = t2.Rows(r)("Dest")
        t1.Rows(r)("Orig") = t2.Rows(r)("Orig")
  Next
```

Answer (score 0):

You can clone the Reference to the Table and delete Rows by call clear like so:

```
NewDataTable= OldDatatable.Clone();
NewDataTable.rows.clear();
```

Comment: From Review:  Hi, please don't answer just with source code. Try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the *expression* property if a calculated value is enough for you without looping the whole datatable.

Assuming you already have a column named *Email*, you can create a column named *UserName* derived from *Email*:

```
dataTable.Columns.Add("UserName", typeof(string), "Email");
```